# Is there a way to dynamically change the location of plotly.js annotations on ternary plots when the figure size is changed?

Tags: javascript, html, plotly, plotly.js

I originally made this same ternary scatter plot using Plotly for Python, and the annotations I added to that automatically change their positions relative to the figure size when the figure size is changed, such that it always looks relatively the same. However, now that I am recreating it with plotly.js, changing the figure size changes the relative positions of annotations. E.g., here is some simplified code

```
// define a function for automatically producing the ternary axes
function makeAxis(title, tickangle, gridcolor) {
    return {
        title: title,
        titlefont: { size: 20 },
        tickangle: tickangle,
        tickfont: { size: 15 },
        tickcolor: '#FFFFFF',
        ticklen: 8,
        min: 0,
        showline: true,
        showgrid: true,
        ticks: 'outside',
        tickmode: 'array',
        tickvals: [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
        gridcolor: gridcolor,
        gridwidth: 1.8,
        tickcolor: gridcolor,
        tickwidth: 1.8,
    };
}

// get our element id for plotting
ternary_plot_div = document.getElementById('ternary_soil')

// set up an empty set of data for base of plot
var ternaryBaseData = [{
    // make base empty plot
    a: [],
    b: [],
    c: [],
    type: 'scatterternary',
},  

    // make outline and fill of sandy clay classification
    {
    a: [0.55, 0.35, 0.35, 0.55],
    b: [0.45, 0.65, 0.45, 0.45],
    c: [0.00, 0.00, 0.20, 0.00],
    type: 'scatterternary',
    mode: 'lines',
    line: {
        width:3, 
        color:'black'
    },
    showlegend: false,
    fill: 'toself',
    fillcolor: 'rgba(1.0, 0.7, 0.7, 0.2)',
    hoverinfo: 'none'
}
];

// set up layout for ternary plot
var figH = 700;
var figW = 700; 
var text_bg_color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'
var annotation_text_color = '#fff'

var layout = {
    // basic aesthetic options
    autosize: false,
    width: figW,
    height: figH,
    
    // Make axes
    ternary: {
        sum: 100,
        aaxis: makeAxis('', 0, 'rgba(0, 230, 230, 0.8)'),
        baxis: makeAxis('', 45, 'rgba(230, 0, 230,0.8)'),
        caxis: makeAxis('', -45, 'rgba(230, 191, 0, 0.8)')
    }, 
    
    // Make plot title, axis titles, and area labels
    annotations: [
        // set title
        {
            showarrow: false,
            text: 'USDA Soil/Sediment<br>Texture Classification',
            x: 0.5,
            y: 1.2,
            font: { size: 25 }
        },

        // set sand axis
        {
            type: 'scatterternary',
            x: 0.5,
            y: -0.15,
            text:"<b>Sand (%)</b>",
            showarrow: false,
            font: {
                size: 26,
                color: '#000'
            },
            align: 'center'
        },

        // set clay axis
        {
            type: 'scatterternary',
            x: 0.015,
            y: 0.555,
            text:"<b>Clay (%)</b>",
            showarrow: false,
            font: {
                size: 26,
                color: '#000'
            },
            align: 'center',
            textangle: -60
        },

        // set silt axis
        {
            type: 'scatterternary',
            x: 0.965,
            y: 0.575,
            text:"<b>Silt (%)</b>",
            showarrow: false,
            font: {
                size: 26,
                color: '#000'
            },
            align: 'center',
            textangle: 60
        },

        // set sandy clay label
        {
            type: 'scatterternary',
            x: 0.218,
            y: 0.418,
            text: '<b>Sandy<br>Clay</b>',
            showarrow: false,
            font: {
                size: 17,
                color: annotation_text_color,
            },
            align: 'center',
            bordercolor: '#000',
            borderwidth: 2,
            borderpad: 2,
            bgcolor: text_bg_color,
            hovertext: 'Sandy clay soil composition:<br>Clay: 35-55%<br>Silt: 0-20%<br>Sand: 45-65%'
        }
]};

// actually produce the plot now
Plotly.newPlot(ternary_plot_div, ternaryBaseData, layout);
```

With an html file linking to the above throw_away_ternary.js file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Import plotly.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.18.2.min.js"></script>
    
    <title>My Soil Ternary Plot</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br><br><br>
    <div id='ternary_soil'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
<!-- Import Ternary plot -->
<script src='.\throw_away_ternary.js'></script>
</html>
```

This code produces this plot:

[image: plot01]

but when I change the height and width variables from 700 to, say, 500

```
var figH = 800;
var figW = 800;
```

I get this output where the top and bottom of the figure are pushed further out and cutoff:

[image]

I have tried playing around with the yref option to fix this, but to no avail. Is there a way to automatically update the positions of annotations when the figure size changes, such that they stay in the same relative position?